# memory segmentaion and segment registers

Tags: operating-system

I do not understand memory segmentation very well , if we have memory of 1MB the segmentation make it segments of 64KB , is this right?

so is there specific segment for every segment register(CS,DS,SS,ES) and can not be changed ?

image for helping understand question

[image]

Comment: Another way to think about it is that the address is simply (%segment_reg << 4) + (address in ax, bx, cx or dx). So you create a 20 bit addressing scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're referring to the old [real mode of x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation#Real_mode).

The values in the segment registers are not strictly static. The idea is that you had 16 bits of architectural address space in the x86, but this was very limiting (64 KB), yet 20 bits of physical address space. Typical addresses would be 16 bits, but addresses in a segment register would be the most significant 16 bits of a 20-bit address. This means they must exist on a 2^4=16-bit boundary. The hardware would then pretend the segment register is a 20-bit base address and the other address (e.g. address of an instruction) is treated as an offset.

Edit: One thing you might be asking is if the segments are mutually exclusive. The segments could overlap partially or completely. This made them quite powerful and quite dangerous.